# how to fix the error ValueError: could not convert string to float in a NLP project in python?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis

I am writing a python code using **jupyter notebook** that train and test  a dataset in order to return a correct sentiment.

The problem that when i try to predict the sentiment of the phrase the system crash and display the below  error :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'this book was so
> interstening it made me not happy'

Note i have an imbalanced dataset so i use  **SMOTE** in order to over_sampling the dataset

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE# for inbalance dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer,TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,classification_report,confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df = pd.read_csv("data/Apple-Twitter-Sentiment-DFE.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1")

df
# data is cleaned using preprocessing functions

# Solving inbalanced dataset using SMOTE 

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vect_df =vectorizer.fit_transform(df["clean_text"])
oversample = SMOTE(random_state = 42)
x_smote,y_smote = oversample.fit_resample(vect_df, df["sentiment"])
print("shape x before SMOTE: {}".format(vect_df.shape))
print("shape x after SMOTE: {}".format(x_smote.shape))
print("balance of targets feild %")
y_smote.value_counts(normalize = True)*100


# split the dataset into train and test 
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x_smote,y_smote,test_size = 0.2,random_state =42)


logreg = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('clf', LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, C=1e5)),
               ])
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(x_test)

print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

# Make prediction 
exl = "this book was so interstening it made me not happy"

logreg.predict(exl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your variable `exl` as the following:

```py
exl = vectorizer.transform(["this book was so interstening it made me not happy"])
```

and then do the prediction.

First, put the testing data in a list and then use `vectorizer` to use features extracted from your training data to do the prediction.

Comment: your answer was correct but can you explain the process and why i need to vectorize the new data ?
it sounds that i did not understand well **vectorizer** process 

i used before **CountVectorizer** and i works but when i used  **TfidfVectorizer** this error start to appear

Comment: Text data requires special preparation before you can start using it for predictive modeling. The words need to be encoded as integers or floating point values for use as input to a machine learning algorithm, called feature extraction (or vectorization). This is where ```sklearn```'s ```TfidfVectorizer()``` comes into play. Your logistic regression won't understand strings; rather, it will understand vectorized data, which simply represents the conversion of the string to a matrix of TF-IDF features.